# Ansible server can't ssh to CentOS 8 machine through -m ping

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ansible, password, centos8

Currently i'm working on an Ansible server that has 4 hosts (3Ubuntu and one CentOS). I can SSH to them without problems. But when i try to run:

`ansible servers -m ping`

this wel be the output:

```
user4@192.168.1.34 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: user4@192.168.1.34: Permission denied (publickey,password).",
    "unreachable": true
}
user3@192.168.1.33 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
user1@192.168.1.31 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
user2@192.168.1.32 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

We can see that the CentOS hsot is unreachable what i want to fix

This is my /etc/ssh/sshd_config file on my CentOS machine:

```
#       $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
#
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# System-wide Crypto policy:
# This system is following system-wide crypto policy. The changes to
# Ciphers, MACs, KexAlgoritms and GSSAPIKexAlgorithsm will not have any
# effect here. They will be overridden by command-line options passed on
# the server start up.
# To opt out, uncomment a line with redefinition of  CRYPTO_POLICY=
# variable in  /etc/sysconfig/sshd  to overwrite the policy.
# For more information, see manual page for update-crypto-policies(8).

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      /home/user4/.ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
UseLogin yes
RSAAuthentication no
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10

#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes

# It is recommended to use pam_motd in /etc/pam.d/sshd instead of PrintMotd,
# as it is more configurable and versatile than the built-in version.
PrintMotd no

#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshoot the ssh auth problem, same as you would without Ansible.

Connection debugging is printed at verbosity 4,  `ansible -vvvv`. Carefully review the generated ssh command. Capture the rest of the verbose output, in case it shows evidence of some other problem.

Review ssh client configuration: those command line options, `ssh_config`, any running `ssh-agent`, authorized keys on the remote. Ansible's ssh connection plugin may use a different key than you are used to interactively. Or, the problem hosts may not have ssh keys deployed correctly.

To get a server perspective, consider [temporarily starting a sshd with significantly more verbose logging](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/295863), say `-ddd` aka `LogLevel DEBUG3`.

Comment: Already tried but it gives me no clue what is going wrong.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details showing what troubleshooting you have done. To start, ssh command that works interactively, and what doesn't found in  `ansible -vvvv` output.